# How to separate the hierarchy values using distinct

Tags: php, postgresql

I have got a table with columns `(srno, Name,  Product, Amount).`
The values  are

```
(1,    Ronak, Iphone,  40000),
                (2,    Ronak, Iphone,  36000),
                (3,    Ronak, Iphone,  38000),
                (4,    Naman, Iphone,  40000),
                (5,    Naman, Ipad,    20000),
                (6,    Nihar, Ipad,    20000),
                (7,    Ronak, Ipad,    19000),
                (8,    Naman, Iphone,  37000),
                (9,    Nihar, Ipad,    40000),
```

I want to fetch the distinct values and store it in another table with their respective parent_id. The output should be like below:

```
(uid, name, parent_id)
(1,  Ronak,   NULL),
(2,  Naman,   NULL),
(3,  Nihar,   NULL),
(4,  Iphone,  1),
(5,  Iphone,  2),
(6,  Ipad,    2),
(7,  Ipad,    3),
(8,  Ipad,    1),
(9,  40000,   4),
(10, 36000,   4),
(11, 38000,   4),
(12, 40000,   5),
(13, 20000,   6),
(14, 20000,   7),
(15, 19000,   8),
(16, 37000,   5),
(17, 40000,   7),
```

The `parent_id` is the `uid` from the same table

Can anyone tell me what query in postgresql can achieve me the desired output. I am using PHP and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

This does the work, but it needs one step per added column. I don't think it can be done with a recursive CTE (maybe with an auxillary array). BTW: strange storage hierarchy!

```
CREATE TABLE oldstuff
        ( num INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , name varchar NOT NULL
        , thing varchar NOT NULL
        , figure INTEGER NOT NULL
        , UNIQUE (name,thing,figure)
        );

INSERT INTO oldstuff(num,name,thing,figure) VALUES
(1, 'Ronak', 'Iphone',  40000),
(2, 'Ronak', 'Iphone',  36000),
(3, 'Ronak', 'Iphone',  38000),
(4, 'Naman', 'Iphone',  40000),
(5, 'Naman', 'Ipad',    20000),
(6, 'Nihar', 'Ipad',    20000),
(7, 'Ronak', 'Ipad',    19000),
(8, 'Naman', 'Iphone',  37000),
(9, 'Nihar', 'Ipad',    40000);

CREATE TABLE newstuff
        ( num SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , thing varchar NOT NULL
        , parent_num INTEGER REFERENCES newstuff(num)
        , UNIQUE (thing,parent_num)
        );

INSERT INTO newstuff(thing)
SELECT DISTINCT os.name
FROM oldstuff os
GROUP BY os.name
        ;

INSERT INTO newstuff(thing,parent_num)
SELECT DISTINCT os.thing, ns.num
FROM oldstuff os
LEFT JOIN newstuff ns ON ns.thing= os.name
GROUP BY os.thing, ns.num
        ;

INSERT INTO newstuff(thing,parent_num)
SELECT os.figure::varchar, COALESCE(n1.num,n0.num)
FROM oldstuff os
JOIN newstuff n0 ON n0.thing= os.name AND n0.parent_num IS NULL
JOIN newstuff n1 ON n1.thing= os.thing AND n1.parent_num =n0.num
        ;

SELECT * FROM newstuff ;
```

Results:

```
   num | thing  | parent_num 
-----+--------+------------
   1 | Naman  |           
   2 | Ronak  |           
   3 | Nihar  |           
   4 | Ipad   |          1
   5 | Ipad   |          2
   6 | Ipad   |          3
   7 | Iphone |          1
   8 | Iphone |          2
   9 | 20000  |          4
  10 | 37000  |          7
  11 | 40000  |          7
  12 | 19000  |          5
  13 | 36000  |          8
  14 | 38000  |          8
  15 | 40000  |          8
  16 | 20000  |          6
  17 | 40000  |          6
```

Comment: I will be having dynamic number of columns. The query of yours is restricted to only 3 columns. Can you help me out with dynamic number of columns.

Comment: Achieved the task by following another approach. Storing the hierarchy with pipe separation in a new column for every row solved my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

May be it could be done with joins easier, but I think most efficient way to do this is to use window functions:

```
with cte as (
    select
        t.Name, t.Product, t.Amount,
        dense_rank() over(order by t.Name) as Name_ID,
        dense_rank() over(order by t.Product, t.Name) as Product_ID,
        dense_rank() over(order by t.Product, t.Name, t.Amount) as Amount_ID
    from Table1 as t
), cte2 as (
    select
        Name, Product, Amount,
        Name_ID,
        max(Name_ID) over() + Product_ID as Product_ID,
        max(Name_ID) over() + max(Product_ID) over() + Amount_ID as Amount_ID
    from cte
)
select distinct
    Name_ID as uid, Name as name, null::int as parent_id
from cte2

union all

select distinct
    Product_ID as uid, Product as name, Name_ID as parent_id
from cte2

union all

select distinct
    Amount_ID as uid, Amount::varchar(10) as name, Product_ID as parent_id
from cte2
order by uid, parent_id
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/46c47/40)</kbd>**

Comment: What if the columns are dynamic?

Comment: @RonakBhandari well I have no time now, I'll check what I can do with dynamic columns later

Comment: Cool!!I will be awaiting for your reply.

Comment: Achieved the task by following another approach. Storing the hierarchy with pipe separation in a new column for every row solved my purpose.